# Spring-boot Gradle shadow jar plugin | missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, gradlew, gradle-shadow-plugin

I setup up a simple web project in spring boot with only the `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")` dependency . When I used `gradlew bootRun`, the application starts up and I am able to get the webpage. If a fat jar is created either manually or through shadow plugin, the jar file refuses to start citing `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` missing. Am I missing some other dependencies. The jar task is modified as

```
jar {
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Comment: What task are you running to create the jar? In order for the Spring Boot to create the uber-jar (containing the embedded servlet container), you need to run `gradle build`.

Comment: I was using gradle jar, thanks for pointing it out. Please post your answer for me to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the Spring Boot to create the uber-jar (containing the embedded servlet container), you need to run `gradle build`.